# Collapse toggle panel (div) which responds to anchor in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

For a FAQ i need a toggle panel similiar to this one:
http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/exapandable-panel/

One specialty is that it always needs to open the box i request via an anchor in the url.
`./faq.php#middle` should open the box in the middle and keep all the other boxes collapsed.
If no anchor is given in the url only the first box should be opened.

How to get this working?

Comment: Just check for the anchor link and then show the element with that id or any other attribute. 

Are you asking for code or help how too write it yourself? I suspect it is the first, if not please ask more specifik what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $(id).show();
    });

    if (location.hash) {
        $(location.hash).show()
    }
});
```